# program bombs when deprecated fix is used

Tags: xcode, string, deprecated

Sorry to ask something that others have already asked. But when I use the published fix, my program bombs

Original that works but gives the NSString deprecated message:

```
textFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
tempArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[textFromFile componentsSeparatedByString: @"||"]];
```

The reported fix:

```
NSString *textFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
tempArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[textFromFile componentsSeparatedByString: @"||"]];
```

Bottom one bombs. What else about the fix am I missing?

(I am using NSString *textFromFile at the top of the file. My (beginner's) intuition is that I am declaring it twice, but if I don't put it at the top of the file, I get undeclared variable error messages. I know I'm not grasping something. Any words of wisdom would be appreciated.)

Comment: Could you provide the crash log? Did you log the variable textFromFile to make sure it isn't nil. Does the file exist?

Comment: Thanks for the question, FelixLam. The bomb message is "thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS". I assume that means it wasn't finding the file. But with the original line in place, instead of the fix, the file is found and read correctly. The only "problem" is that warning about the stringWithContentsOfFile being deprecated.

Comment: deprecated does not necessarily mean stopped working. could you provide a crash log? i.e. the backtrace of the crash which should tell you which line of your code crashed.

Comment: Could you also log the error: `NSError *err=nil; NSString *textFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err]; NSLog(@"Err: %@", err);`

Comment: Sorry, but I've been away for a while. I'm new at this and have to figure out how you even see the crash log. I have the console showing but I assume you want something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem with my situation. Here it is for anyone else who runs into the same issue.

In the text file which was read into the string textFromFile, I had used || to separate the items that were then to be transferred into the tempArray.

The old deprecated way worked. The new, officially preferred method, with that extra encoding parameter, bombed.

When I switched the separators to jj instead of ||, the new method worked.

I now have no warnings about using deprecated syntax.